# How can I use Linq to entities to group a collection without using anonymous types?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-entities, grouping

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386922.aspx) has an example about grouping on multiple properties:

```
Dim custRegionQuery = From cust In db.Customers _
    Group cust.ContactName By Key = New With _
        {cust.City, cust.Region} Into grouping = Group

For Each grp In custRegionQuery
    Console.WriteLine(vbNewLine & "Location Key: {0}", grp.Key)
    For Each listing In grp.grouping
        Console.WriteLine(vbTab & "{0}", listing)
    Next
Next
```

Suppose I have a real type (i.e. not anonymous) that has properties for each element of the key, as well as a property for the group, so something a little like:

```
Public Class CustomerRegionGroup

    Public Sub New(city As String, region as String, customers As IEnumerable(Of Customer))
        Me.City = city
        Me.Region = region
        Me.Customers = customers
    End Sub

    Public Property City As String
    Public Property Region As String
    Public Property Customers As IEnumerable(Of Customer)
End Class
```

Is it possible to rewrite the original query to just return `IEnumerable(Of CustomerRegionGroup)`, or do I have to use the anonymous type, and run a second query on the result of the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a lot simpler than some of the things I'd tried, as I didn't appreciate that you could just do:

```
Dim custRegionQuery = From cust In db.Customers _
                      Group By cust.City, cust.Region _
                      Into Group _
                      Select New CustomerRegionGroup(City, Region, Group)
```